# appirator setSignificantEventsUntilPrompt iOS

Tags: ios, appirater

Can we use two different `setSignificantEventsUntilPrompt` within one application?Say for example I have two category(awesome,better)named button.I need to show appRating AFTER FIRST SUCCESSFUL HIT of `AWESOME`button or 2 SUCCESSFUL HITS OF `BETTER`button.Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify Appirater as per your need. One way of achieving what you are looking for is by creating another routine in Appirater class that increments the significant event by 'X' number

Here is how I do.

In **Appirater.h**, Declare a new routine for tracking more significant events

1. (void)userDidMoreSignificantEvent:(BOOL)canPromptForRating;

In **Appirater.m** Modify the following

1. Modify - (void)incrementSignificantEventCount to accept a parameter - (void)incrementSignificantEventCount:(int)count
2. Inside incrementSignificantEventCount, replace sigEventCount++; with
   sigEventCount = sigEventCount + count;
3. Modify incrementSignificantEventAndRate:(BOOL)canPromptForRating to
   accept another parameter
   -(void)incrementSignificantEventAndRate:(BOOL)canPromptForRating withCount:(int)count
4. Inside incrementSignificantEventAndRate, replace [self
   incrementSignificantEventCount]; with [self
   incrementSignificantEventCount:count];
5. Replace userDidSignificantEvent: routine with the following code

   - (void)userDidSignificantEvent:(BOOL)canPromptForRating {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW,
     0),
                    ^{
                        [[Appirater sharedInstance] incrementSignificantEventAndRate:canPromptForRating withCount:1];
                    }); }
6. Define new routine to track more significant event

   - (void)userDidMoreSignificantEvent:(BOOL)canPromptForRating {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW,
     0),
                    ^{
                        [[Appirater sharedInstance] incrementSignificantEventAndRate:canPromptForRating withCount:2];
                    }); }

Now you will be able to use methods,

> [Appirater userDidSignificantEvent:YES] to increment by 1
>
> [Appirater userDidMoreSignificantEvent:YES] to increment by 2